# Makefile ignore segfault

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use GNU Make to automatically convert a set of `.mmpz` files to `.ogg` files using `lmms`. There's currently a bug in `lmms` that causes it to segfault after producing the output file, leading `make` to spit out errors. Adding a `-` before the rule forces `make` to ignore the error and prevents it from removing the output file, but error messages are still produced. I've tried the following:

```
-@lmms -r $(MPPZDIR)/$*.mmpz -f ogg -o $(OGGDIR)/$*.ogg
-@lmms -r $(MPPZDIR)/$*.mmpz -f ogg -o $(OGGDIR)/$*.ogg 2> /dev/null
-@lmms -r $(MPPZDIR)/$*.mmpz -f ogg -o $(OGGDIR)/$*.ogg || true
```

which all produce something along the lines of

```
/bin/sh: line 1:  3325 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) lmms -r resources/mmpz/song.mmpz -f ogg -o content/music/song.ogg 2> /dev/null
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'content/music/song.ogg' failed
make: [content/music/song.ogg] Error 139 (ignored)
```

Considering that the segfault is expected and does not indicate a failure to produce the output file, is there a way to hide this error until the bug is fixed?
`make -i` also still seems to output the errors.

Comment: `|| true` has the same effect as the leading `-` in getting make to ignore the failure of the `lmms` command.

Comment: @MarkGaleck In that respect I agree with you completely. `|| true` is absolutely preferable to the leading `-`. My point was mostly that both are not necessary as in line three of the OPs example.

Comment: @Etan well I take it back, sorry, not a good point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
define EXPECTED_FAIL
if ! { $1 ; } 2>$@.temp; then \
    echo EXPECTED FAILURE: ; cat $@.temp; \
fi
endef

<target>: <prerequisites>
    $(call EXPECTED_FAIL, lmms -r $(MPPZDIR)/$*.mmpz -f ogg -o $(OGGDIR)/$*.ogg )
```

Comment: This still prints a segmentation fault message for each failure (before the EXPECTED FAILURE: is printed).

Comment: @murphyslaw oh I see that is because segmentation fault is not a "normal" error message, it does not get printed on the process stderr.  Hang on let me look into this.